# How to change the color of stroke in all roads in Google static maps api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to change the color of road strokes in Google static map API. As far as I remember, I used to do it like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.021254,%20-118.285296&zoom=15&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&style=feature%3aroad%7celement%3ageometry.stroke%7ccolor%3a0x000000

The above query must be change the stroke of all roads to black. But it only works on highways. Has something changed in the API, or am I missing something?

Comment: Did  you just want to change the stroke?  Or the fill also?  There are issues with the stroke of some roads currently ([Issue 10197  Bug: Road stroke styles only partially applied](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10197))

Comment: @geocodezip, thank you very much! I am having the same problem discussed at the given link. Fills work properly, but strokes work only on highways. So seems that it is bug in the API, or they decided to remove this feature.

Comment: I think they changed the default styling of Google Maps and that created issues for existing styled maps (introduced a bug) in styling for all types of Google Maps (Google Maps Javascript API v3 and Static Maps).

Comment: THanks man. I spent so much time trying to figure out what was going on, it was killing me.